# Why I cannot install the newest version of R on Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu

I have tried removing and installing again R with sudo apt-get install r-base but it keeps installing R 3.0.2, while there is already R 3.2.0.. With the older version I cannot install some dependencies so I need the new one. I also tried to install manually the 3.2.0 but it didn't suceed... Someone knows what to do?

Comment: You need to follow [these instructions](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/).

Comment: I tried to follow the above mentioned instructions but it keep installing R 3.0.2...

Comment: It is written exactly what grubjesic posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that you use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS first add this line:

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

to the file **/etc/apt/sources.list**

Then add key by typing:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

And finally install R by typing next commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Finally something worked.... after wasting hours on it :P

Comment: You just needed to follow the README file.